# Can't use SSH with any port except 22

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ssh, port

I've been trying to change the port used by sshd on my Ubuntu 22.04 VPS (which I think I've succeeded in doing) but can't connect from my home PC if it is set to anything except port 22. I am using ssh key passwordless login, but I wouldn't have thought that would affect this.

I changed my /etc/ssh/sshd_config on my remote to a new port (say 11111) and restarted the service. `sudo systemctl status ssh` shows:

```
Active: active (running)
...
localhost sshd[13641]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 11111
localhost sshd[13641]: Server listening on :: port 11111
localhost systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
```

When I attempt to connect to the server using `ssh -p 11111 <myserverip>`, I get ssh: Connection timed out. If I do the same with port 22, I get `ssh: Connection refused`.

I've added my new port to `ufw`: `sudo ufw allow 11111/tcp`. Running `sudo ufw status` shows:

```
Status: active
To            Action    From
--            ------    ----
22/tcp        ALLOW     Anywhere
11111/tcp     ALLOW     Anywhere
22/tcp(v6)    ALLOW     Anywhere (v6)
11111/tcp(v6) ALLOW     Anywhere (v6)
```

If I change /etc/ssh/sshd_config back to port 22, I can connect as normal.  Perhaps it is another firewall/filter that I am missing? Or is it something to do with my client setup?

Comment: Are you connecting through the internet? If there is a router before the ssh server, have you forwarded port 11111 to the server?

Comment: I don't need to forward the port on my home router for outgoing connections, do I?

Comment: No, only on the recipient router. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Provide the verbose OpenSSH Server logs, after a client attempts to connect on port 1111. We also would need the uncommented non-default lines from your `sshd_config`.

Comment: Where is your VPS? Many/most VPS providers have an additional "firewall" outside the VPS (usually controlled in the web interface associated with the networking screen) where you also need to map port 1111 for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

@davidgo and @harrymc were on the right track - My VPS provider has a firewall implemented outside of the actual VPS, with only port 22 exposed. Adding a new "allow" rule through the VPS provider's UI did the trick!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).